# CommonsRequestLoggingFilter not logging with log4j2 config in my spring web reactive app

Tags: log4j2, reactive, spring-web

Can anyone please help me if `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` can be used in spring web reactive app using log4j2? I have tried configuring it, but it does not log anything. Please correct my understanding if its wrong. Does it use commons-logging and cannot be used with log4j2?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely that you haven't configured the filter correctly. As the name says, it is a filter. So you might have to add something like that to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>includeClientInfo</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>includePayload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>includeQueryString</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>requestLoggingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

You could also do this via the WebInitializer and Java.

You'll need this, if you are not running your application by Spring Boot. Spring Boot would do that kind of configuration for you. That's why most examples don't show that part of configuration.

In addition to this, please don't forget to adjust your logging accordingly. Most examples are done using Logback, but with the modern Log4j it is:

```
 <Logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter" level="debug" additivity="false">
     <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
 </Logger>
```